# Exchange-related tabs in Active Directory with Windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-7, exchange-2007, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ADUC Exchange tabs - Windows 7 & Exchange 2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/189964/aduc-exchange-tabs-windows-7-exchange-2003)

Hello,
I recently moved to Windows 7 and everything is fine except that I can't get the Microsoft Exchange-realted tabs back in AD. They're very helpful in dealing with Exchange related fields remotely.
I used to get them on my XP mechine by installing Exchange System Manager with the AD Adminpack.

After installling Windows 7 I installed the new Adminpack that is compatible with Windows 7, and also installed Exchange Management Console which replaced the Exchange System Manager.

The problem is that I still don't have the Exchange tabs in AD and I'm out of ideas and Google isn't that helpful.

I'm using Windows 7 32-bit Pro, Exchange 2007 SP1, and Windows Server 2003 for AD.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ditto that it's a Duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for the dupe. Great thread, will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange 2007 there is no longer the Exchange Tabs in AD instead you use the Exchange Management console

if you really need to manage exchange from AD U/C then you can use

http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/managing-exchange-2007-recipients-active-directory-users-computers-mmc-snap-in.html